# How can I insert hashmap keys into Treeset or LinkedHashSet

Tags: treeset, linkedhashset

I have a HashMap whose keys I want to retrieve. How can I set them to LinkedHashSet or TreeSet. I'm seeing the below exception 
"java.util.HashMap$KeySet cannot be cast to java.util.TreeSet" while insert. How can I do that?

Comment: Please follow this guide for info on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case you want to post the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation bellow, you can call the Constructor of TreeSet with java.util.HashMap$KeySet:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html